# Make This Input Function Faster

Tags: python, function, performance, coding-efficiency

I'm practicing some exam questions and I've encountered a time limit issue that I can't figure out. I think its to do with how I'm iterating through the inputs.

It's the famous titanic dataset so I won't bother printing a sample of the df as I'm sure everyone is familiar with it.

The function compares the similarity between two passengers which are provided as input. Also, I am mapping the Sex column with integers in order to compare between passengers you'll see below.

I was also thinking it could be how I'm indexing and locating the values for each passenger but again I'm not sure

The function is as follows and the time limit is 1 second but when no_of_queries == 100 the function takes 1.091s.

```
df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")

mappings = {'male': 0, 'female':1}
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].map(mappings)


def function_similarity(no_of_queries):  

  for num in range(int(no_of_queries)):
     
      x = input()
      passenger_a, passenger_b = x.split()
      passenger_a, passenger_b = int(passenger_a), int(passenger_b)

      result = 0  
      if int(df[df['PassengerId'] == passenger_a]['Pclass']) == int(df[df['PassengerId'] == passenger_b]['Pclass']):  
          result += 1  
      if int(df[df['PassengerId'] ==passenger_a]['Sex']) == int(df[df['PassengerId'] ==passenger_b]['Sex']):  
          result += 3  
      if int(df[df['PassengerId'] ==passenger_a]['SibSp']) == int(df[df['PassengerId'] ==passenger_b]['SibSp']):  
          result += 1  
      if int(df[df['PassengerId'] == passenger_a]['Parch']) == int(df[df['PassengerId'] == passenger_b]['Parch']):  
          result += 1  
      result += max(0, 2 - abs(float(df[df['PassengerId'] ==passenger_a]['Age']) - float(df[df['PassengerId'] ==passenger_b]['Age'])) / 10.0)
      result += max(0, 2 - abs(float(df[df['PassengerId'] ==passenger_a]['Fare']) - float(df[df['PassengerId'] ==passenger_b]['Fare'])) / 5.0)
      print(result / 10.0)



function_similarity(input())
```

Comment: Why not calculate `df[df['PassengerId'] == passenger_a]` and `df[df['PassengerId'] == passenger_b]` once and then further index for each `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate passenger row by id value once per passengers a and b.

```
df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")

mappings = {'male': 0, 'female':1}
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].map(mappings)


def function_similarity(no_of_queries):  

  for num in range(int(no_of_queries)):
     
      x = input()
      passenger_a, passenger_b = x.split()
      passenger_a, passenger_b = df[df['PassengerId'] == int(passenger_a)], df[df['PassengerId'] == int(passenger_b)]

      result = 0  
      if int(passenger_a['Pclass']) == int(passenger_b['Pclass']):  
          result += 1  
      if int(passenger_a['Sex']) == int(passenger_b['Sex']):  
          result += 3  
      if int(passenger_a['SibSp']) == int(passenger_b['SibSp']):  
          result += 1  
      if int(passenger_a['Parch']) == int(passenger_b['Parch']):  
          result += 1  
      result += max(0, 2 - abs(float(passenger_a['Age']) - float(passenger_b['Age'])) / 10.0)
      result += max(0, 2 - abs(float(passenger_a['Fare']) - float(passenger_b['Fare'])) / 5.0)
      print(result / 10.0)



function_similarity(input())
```

Comment: yes I see now, I had a suspicion it was this but I've not filtered a df in a variable much prior so it wasn't in my mind. Thank you for the insight a nice lesson for me today.